# How do I install drivers for a Logitech webcam?

Tags: drivers, webcam, logitech

I have tried to set up a [Logitech C270](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/7079) webcam, and it will not work even though this webcam is one on a list of compatible webcams.

How do I get the drivers for this webcam?

Comment: Install "cheese" if not installed and start it. We use GENERIC drivers and webcams should "just work"; In windows you get drivers per hardware but this is not Windows. Either there is a generic driver or it wont work. 3rd party drivers are rare (video, some NICs, 1 per brand of printer but that's about it).

Answer (score 2):

After installing package `guvcview` my c170 worked with that tool *and* cheese.

Answer (score 0):

If cheese doesn't work, try luvcview:

```
sudo apt-get install luvcview
```

luvcview works with some Logictec cameras that cheese doesn't

Comment: There is no luvcview in Ubuntu 15.10. I have a Logitech C110 that working but with bad resolution. In my Dell inspiron 1750 the build in webcam working fine. I am searching a way o dolve this